# JSON to Python List

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

**Context**: Using Visual Studio Code, trying to convert my JSON response into a Python list, so I can add it to a Google Sheet.

I'd like to convert my response into a List of JSON Lists (like the "working example" below)

**Working Example**

```
RandomJson = [
    ['hello',2],
    ["hi",3]
]

bla = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range='sheet1!A1', valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":RandomJson}).execute()
```

I've tried a number of ways, but I cannot get "My Data Set" into the "Desired Format"

Can anybody help please?

**My Data Set**

```
{
  "data": {
    "tokens": [
      {
        "name": "FMX Token",
        "symbol": "FMXT"
      },
      {
        "name": "HeavensGate",
        "symbol": "HATE"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shrimp Swap",
        "symbol": "Shrimp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Desired Format**

```
RandomJson = [
    ["FMX Token","FMXT"],
    ["HeavensGate","HATE"],
    ["Shrimp Swap","Shrimp"]
]
```

**Edit - Full Code**

I have made a change suggested in the comments, and also added "j = json.loads(JsonData)"

I'm now getting an error:

"googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets//values/sheet1%21A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "FMX Token" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."

```
import requests
import gspread
import json
import os.path
import pprint
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'CredEDs.json'
SCOPES = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = ''

service = build('sheets','v4',credentials=creds)

sheet = service.spreadsheets()

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.thegraph.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://info.uniswap.org',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://info.uniswap.org',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,es-419;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
}

data = rb'{"operationName":"tokens","variables":{"skip":500},"query":"query tokens($skip: Int\u0021) {\n tokens(first: 500, skip: $skip) {\n name\n symbol\n}\n}\n"}'
response = requests.post('https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2', headers=headers, data=data)

JsonData = response.text

j = json.loads(JsonData)

result = {token['name']: token['symbol'] for token in j['data']['tokens']}

bla = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range='sheet1!A1', valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":result}).execute()
```

Answer (score 9):

It's as simple as:

```
result = [[token['name'], token['symbol']] for token in data['data']['tokens']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Unfortunately I got: 
"TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Here is a larger sample of the code just for context

```
data = rb'{"operationName":"tokens","variables":{"skip":500},"query":"query tokens($skip: Int\u0021) {\n tokens(first: 500, skip: $skip) {\n name\n symbol\n}\n}\n"}'
response = requests.post('https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2', headers=headers, data=data)

JsonData = response.text


result = {token['name']: token['symbol'] for token in data['data']['tokens']}

print (result)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your example probably not exactly as you described... please include some more code, and question? Is the example you provided is a string or converted via json module?

Comment: Firstly then, if it is another issue, thanks @go2nivana for helping out. 

adirabargil I've added more code and another error into the "Edit" section

Comment: It looks like the response is in String format, so you need to convert the string to JSON.
import json
JSONTypeData = json.loads(JsonData)

Comment: Hi @AnkitSahay, thanks for the suggestion, I added that (see Edited section in the original post) and I'm getting a strange error, but I think it is a step closer to victory!

Comment: @ubaidshaikh it isn't usually, just didn't think it made sense to share as the sheet isn't public

Comment: In the desired format that you have shown above, it seems like you need a list of list, but the result variable in the above is a dictionary

Comment: @ubaidshaikh, yes a list of lists is what I require, the initial suggestion on this thread by go2nirvana prints the output as `{'FMX Token': 'FMXT', 'HeavensGate': 'HATE', 'Shrimp Swap': 'Shrimp''}` which isn't quite what I need `[['FMX Token','FMXT'],['HeavensGate','HATE'],['Shrimp Swap','Shrimp']]`

Comment: Do you mean this code `result = [[token['name'], token['symbol']] for token in data['data']['tokens']]` is printing this output `{'FMX Token': 'FMXT', 'HeavensGate': 'HATE', 'Shrimp Swap': 'Shrimp''}`?

Comment: @ubaidshaikh yes, `JsonData = response.text

j = json.loads(JsonData)

result = {token['name']:token['symbol'] for token in j['data']['tokens']}` results in `{'FMX Token': 'FMXT', 'HeavensGate': 'HATE', 'Shrimp Swap': 'Shrimp'}` (ignore the additional ', after Shrimp, that was a typo before)

Comment: And you want the result to be like `[
    ["FMX Token","FMXT"],
    ["HeavensGate","HATE"],
    ["Shrimp Swap","Shrimp"]
]`, right?

Comment: @ubaidshaikh correct, apologies if I was unclear!

Comment: Then in that case, you should be using this `result = [[token['name'], token['symbol']] for token in j['data']['tokens']]` instead of this `result = {token['name']: token['symbol'] for token in j['data']['tokens']}`

Comment: @ubaidshaikh awesome!!  thanks it works. appreciate everybody's time, very kind of you all

Comment: Thank you. It was fun. ✌